# difficulty upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

**Box type**: Dell Inspiron E1505 with a Core2Duo and 2GB RAM

**Problem history**: I recently upgraded my machine from a 12.04 to a 14.04. Everything went smooth and within a few hours, I was prompted to upgrade to 16.04 but the upgrade to 16.04 and I lost all my data (which is fine since I backed up all my files). Having no 16.04 or 14.04 installation disks, I reinstalled 12.04 and tried going through the same process again but was unable to upgrade to even 14.04. But I was lucky the third time around and I have a working machine with 14.04 now.

**Question**

- Why could this be happening?
- Should I try installing Ubuntu 16.04 through an installing disc instead?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should install 16.04 LTS using a USB stick, the year is 2017, you know.

Comment: Yes, use a 16.04 installation disc or USB stick. It'll be a cleaner install than one that's been upgraded twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware seems to be outdated (Core2Duo). Ubuntu 16.04 requires 2GB of system memory, try adding some more RAM. Try downloading the ISO from Ubuntu's site to a USB stick. When you proceed to download the ISO, there are recommend system requirements. https://www.ubuntu.com/download